# Fitting image in the column of a table

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I need my image to be 20% in width, and 20% in height, but when I used 20% in width, it stretched the width of the column out to where there's a lot of white space to the right of the image. I don't want the extra white spaces. How do I fix that?

```css
img {
width: 20%;
height: 20%; 
}
```

```html
<table border = '1'>
 
<tr>
<td> <img src = "http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/multimedia/archive/00309/108787995_309592c.jpg" height="42" width="42"> </td>
<td> This is a cat! </td> 
</tr> 
 
</table>
```

Comment: first of all, get rid of the `height="42" width="42"` in your img tag. Also, where is your table width defined?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're after, but getting rid of the inline height and width attributes and the width css property should fix it.

```css
img {
    height: 20%; 
}
```

```html
<table border = '1'>
 
<tr>
<td> <img src = "http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/multimedia/archive/00309/108787995_309592c.jpg"> </td>
<td> This is a cat! </td> 
</tr> 
 
</table>
```